# How can I handle dynamically "incompatible types" (possible lossy conversion) error?

Tags: java

In the following example code:

```
int[] ary = new int[10];
//Double[] ary = new Double[10];
double x = 10.0; 

...

if (Double.class.isInstance(ary))
  ary[0] = x;
else 
  ary[0] = (int)x;
```

I would like to test a program by the setting the array 'ary' either as integer or as double. Unfortunately, I can't. If I set 'ary[]' as integer, the assignment 'ary[0] = x' procudes compliter error "Incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int". if I set 'ary[]' as double, the error is produced with the assignment 'ary[0] = (int)x'. In short, it's a no-win situation. The only thing I can do is commenting out one of the two assignments. However, I have to do this a dozen of times. Not practical at all! Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: `Double.class.isInstance(ary)` is false

Comment: `Double.class.isInstance(ary)` will always evaluates to `false`, an array is never a `Double`, whatever the type of the elements it contains. You should remove those 12 occurrences of terrible code. If you're storing `double`s use a `double[]` and be done with it. If you want an array that can contain both `int` and `double` you could technically use an `Object[]` array, but trust me that you'd soon find out why it's a bad idea.

Comment: You can't do the exact thing that you're looking for. The `if` statement may be able to check the type of `ary` at *run time* but the compiler checks the type in *both* the 'true' and 'false' branches at *compile time*.

Comment: When the compiler sees `Double.class.isInstance(ary)`, all it knows is that the code is calling a method called `isInstance()`. It doesn't know what that method does. Therefore when it gets inside the 'true' and 'false' braches of the `if`, it doesn't know whether `ary` is a `Double[]` or not in either branch.

Comment: @Aaron, I know the code is not OK, otherwise it would work!! But it's a logical code. Plus, I didn't know that 'Double.class.isInstance(ary)' is always false! It doesn't make sense. And then, how else to check the type of the array? And Object is indeed a bad idea.

Comment: Please tell me what you're trying to achieve ! While what you're doing may seem like a good idea for someone coming from a loosely-typed language, I'm sure there's a much more idiomatic solution for a strongly-typed language. Why are you trying to store different types in a single array? How are the array and its elements going to be used? user7's solution surprised me (I wasn't familiar with the `Number` class), but in addition to the overhead at construction it has the same problem as an `Object[]` solution : you need to "cast" the `Number` to the desired type every time you want to use it

Comment: @Aaron I don't think Apostolos is trying to store different types in the same array. I think he's got a homogeneous array (i.e. all elements are the same type) but sometimes he wants to make it an `int[]` and other times he wants to make it a `double[]` for testing purposes, and he wants to make that change in only one place. Is that the case Apostolos?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException that seems likely, sorry for the misunderstanding Apostolos. Still not a great idea IMO, but I think you can use reflection/introspection to do that. I'll check and come back with an example.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? It uses method overloading, so a different method will be selected *at compile time* for each different type of `ary`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Yeah [this](https://ideone.com/UnCtlN) works but is a bad idea. I hadn't seen your answer, it's much better.

Comment: @Aaron, you are too strict! You could show a little more toletance, I believe. It's not a University IT class here, and you are not grading papers. This is a help community.

Comment: And I'm trying to help you (although I'm by no mean a professional teacher, and I'll easily agree I can be too blunt) by strongly insisting this is a bad idea ;) Not only a bad idea if the sense it will produce "imperfect code", but bad idea in the sense you will waste your time trying to do something that isn't meant to be done in a strongly-typed language. Anyway these comments have been going on for way too long, it's time I pull my fingers out of my ass and make the effort of posting an answer that justifies why I think so.

Comment: Yes, @DodgyCodeException, this is exactly the case. I think @Aaron has got it all wrong. Anyway, @user7 offered a great solution (see further below). And the assignmnet works both ways: `ary[0] = x` and `x = ary[0].doubleValue()`. Just that; no checks whatsoever.

Comment: I believe this question was finally valuable for the community, despite some negative comments. And only one member could offer a really working solution (up to now).

Answer (score 3):

If you want a generic container for storing both `int` and `double`, use `Number` class

```
Number[] numbers = new Number[10]
numbers[0] = 10; //int
numbers[1] = 10.0; //double
```

But beware that the two assignments involve boxing i.e, convert the primitive to the corresponding wrapper. In other words, it involves the creation of objects of the wrapper class corresponding to the primitive. So, here `10` and `10.0` are boxed to objects of type `Integer` and `Double` respectively.

Comment: Nice, in general. (I have never used the Number class!)  However, I cannot do the reverse, i.e. 'x = number[0]', whether 'x' is an integer or double. I get an error "Incompatible types: Number cannot be converted to int (or double)". I upvoted your reply because it solves the case as I presented it. (I wanted to keep the code as simple as possible.) Do you have a solution for the "reverse" case too?

Comment: @Apostolos If you what type a particular array element is you can do `number[0].intValue()` or `number[0].doubleValue()`

Comment: This is great! Thank you, @user7.  (I had no idea about this method)

Answer (score 1):

You can use polymorphism:

```
int ary[] = new int[10];
// double ary[] = new double[10];

System.out.println(foo(ary));  // prints 'int'
```

using overloaded methods:

```
String foo(int[] ary) {
    ary[0] = 1234;
    return "int";
}

String foo(double[] ary) {
    ary[0] = 1234.5678;
    return "double";
}
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but you see, I want to assign 'ary[0]' a double value depending on whether the array is integer or double. These methods return string, which is of no use.